# What do conditions target in uniqueness validators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model

I have the following validator in my model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :item_id, conditions: -> { where.not(status: "published") }
```

What does the condition target here? Does it prevent the validator itself to look on the table row if there is status: "published" or is it an extension for the uniqueness validator to exclude the rows with status: "published" in the uniqueness (yes, there is a difference)?

Is there also a difference between the above validator and the following, assuming that `status_published?` is a method checking for the status to be "published" or not?

```
validates_uniqueness_of :item_id, :unless => lambda { status_published? }
```

And finally, if there is no difference, how can I accomplish the second case, where uniqueness validator will check if the value is **unique only in the rows which are true for the condition?**

Comment: If it helps, the unique validator could work also like "there may be only one unpublished status scoped to the item id".

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of), conditions limit the constraint to the set of records that match them, so the validation doesn't run at all if those said conditions aren't matched.

On a side-note, if you're doing this in Rails 4, you may want to look at the [new `validates` syntax](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness):

`validates :item_id, uniqueness: true, unless: :status_published?`